# Sets of Prime and Composite Numbers

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, twin-primes

We know that all primes are of the form $ 6k ± 1 $ with the exception of 2 and 3.

We also know that **not** all numbers of the form $ 6k ± 1 $ are prime.

This leads to four distinct sets of pairs adjacent to a multiple of six:

1. Twin Primes, Example: $ 5, 7 $ (prime followed by a prime)
2. Twin Composites, Example: $ 119, 121 $ (composite followed by a composite)
3. Prime-Composite, Example: $ 23, 25 $ (prime followed by a composite)
4. Composite-Prime, Example: $ 35, 37 $ (composite followed by a prime)

The Twin Prime Conjecture states that there are infinitely many Twin Primes, but has yet to be proven.

**Could it be proven that any of these four sets are infinite?**

Comment: prime composites and composite primes are badly chosen terms

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen: Based on what criteria? Have they been established? What would you name them?

Comment: "prime composite" is a prima facie oxymoron.  I might recommend the four names "PP", "PC", "CP", and "CC", although those names aren't great.  (I heartily endorse proposed improvements.)

Comment: It can be proven that at least one of these four sets is infinite.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The composite-composite case is easy.  By the Chinese remainder theorem there are infinitely many solutions of, for example,
$$x\equiv0\pmod6\ ,\quad x\equiv1\pmod5\ ,\quad x\equiv-1\pmod7\ .$$
And for any such $x$ greater than $6$ we have $x-1,x+1$ are adjacent to a multiple of $6$, and $x-1$ is a multiple of $5$ and hence composite, and $x+1$ is a multiple of $7$ and hence composite.

---

The composite-prime case follows from Dirichlet's theorem (which is not easy to prove).  Consider the numbers $x=30k+6$.  Then the numbers $x-1,x+1$ are adjacent to a multiple of $6$; and the numbers $x+1$ are prime infinitely often; and the numbers $x-1$ are always composite.

---

Similarly, $x=30k-6$ covers the prime-composite case.

---

And as you mentioned, the prime-prime case is still unsolved.

---

Alternative proof for the composite case: consider the numbers
$$x=6\times119\times121k+120\ .$$
Then $x-1$ is always a multiple of $119$, and $x+1$ is always a multiple of $121$.

Or to keep the numbers a bit smaller, $x=6\times7\times11k+120$.

Comment: Very nice. +1.  .

Comment: Has a probability distribution been established for these four sets? Such that the probability of a random multiple of six, or a multiple of six below or above a certain number, belongs to either of these four sets?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  However I am definitely not an expert in this subject.

Comment: @lurker: Given that a nonzero lower bound for the asymptotic probability of prime+prime would solve the twin primes conjecture, I think we can safely say that no such lower bound is known.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple to construct an infinite sequence for the *Prime-Composite* case:

$$23+60n,25+60n$$

$25+60n$ will generate an infinite amount of composite numbers, all of which are divisible by $5$ (in fact, it will generate **only** composite numbers).

$23+60n$ will generate an infinite amount of prime numbers, since $23$ and $60$ are coprime integers (according to [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)).

---

It is very simple to construct an infinite sequence for the *Composite-Prime* case:

$$35+60n,37+60n$$

$35+60n$ will generate an infinite amount of composite numbers, all of which are divisible by $5$ (in fact, it will generate **only** composite numbers).

$37+60n$ will generate an infinite amount of prime numbers, since $37$ and $60$ are coprime integers (according to [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)).

Answer (score 0):

Case $2$ is answered so I will address the others.  For case $3$, by Dirichlet's theorem there are an infinite number of primes of the form $10 \cdot n + 3$, and $10 \cdot n + 5$ is always divisible by $5$.  There is a similar example for case $4$.

Comment: But the OP also wants the "in between" number to be a multiple of $6$, if I read the question correctly.

Comment: @David Correct. All four sets contain numbers adjacent to a multiple of six.